# .NET Core Docker app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk can't access RDS MySQL instance

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a web service built in .NET Core 3.1 and stored in the AWS Elastic Container Registry. When I deploy it to an Elastic Beanstalk Docker environment, the deployment goes fine, but it can't access RDS.

Everything else works, including connections to my MongoDB Atlas instance. When I deploy it through SSH on a different EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2, the connection works fine. The EBS environment and the EC2 instance have the same security groups. I've used Dockerrun.aws.json, I've used zip files, I've used the plain docker file, I've deployed from Visual Studio. Nothing can connect from the EBS environment. I've terminated both the EC2 and EBS and spun up new ones, with the same result.

Are there any security settings or permissions that may be set differently using Elastic Beanstalk? Have I configured something wrong?

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
        "Name": "*********.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/***-app:latest",
        "Update": "true"
    },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /***-app
COPY dockerpub . 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnet.dll"]
```